# Count down timer for export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a timer for an export json to csv process.

If the export process takes 5 seconds. Then, the system will show 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

I find it is impossible to predict the duration of the export process.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Export of what to where?

Comment: What do you mean by *impossible to predict the duration of the export process*?

Comment: Let say I want to export a json to csv. If the duration is 7 seconds. The system will show 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 then show the word succeed.

Comment: Looks to me like you would need to write code related to the export to be able to "estimate", not predict - because it is technically impossible to be a 100% sure how long it will take until it is actually exported.

Comment: you can't really have a timer for something if you have no notion of how long it will take to do something. you can time how long it will take but if you're after a something like that you will have to run some tests to see how long various csv sizes take to export and the try to estimate it?

Comment: At most you can have a progress indicator from your request

Comment: Do you have any javascript library recommended?